# Can I define a category as a monoid with partially defined multiplication?

Tags: category-theory, semigroups, universal-algebra

A groupoid can either be thought of as a category whose morphisms are isomorphisms, or as a generalization of a group whose multiplication is only partially defined. Can I do a similar thing with categories and monoids? More generally, if I have some algebraic structure X on a one object category, can I think of a many object generalization of that structure (an "Xoid") as a generalization of X with partially defined operations?

Comment: yes, you can. Though renaming 'category' to 'monoidoid' is unlikely to be popular.

Comment: Well of course I'm not concerned with naming, I'm just curious about different ways to think about familiar structures.

Comment: It is more productive to think the other way around: a monoid is a category with just one object. So all proofs you have for categories are valid for monoids (plus there are others which only hold for monoids)

Comment: That's what I usually do in a working situation. I'm asking not out of necessity but out of curiosity. I want to make sure I'm making the right connections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is colloquially known as [oidification](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/horizontal+categorification) for the reasons that you suspect. Interestingly, that link suggests that the 'exception to the rule' is precisely your example of oidifying a monoid.

Comment: One of my favorite passages from the nlab: "And finally the exception from the rule: a many-object monoid is not called a monoidoid – but is called a category! :-)"

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg The nlab is a curious mixture of extremely compact and abstract explanations, peppered with the most charming side comments and narration. It's really endearing :).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert, but I think that a category is a special type of partial monoid with partial identity elements satisfying some axioms. Unfortunately, I don't know what is the exact list of axioms.